# where to find the implementation of System.Val?

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to find the implementation of the intrinsic function `System.val(..)`?

This function works only with **unicodeString** and I would like to make it working with **AnsiString** also ... is there any replacement of this function that works with **ansiString**?

Comment: Why do you need a new function for that? You can pass an AnsiString to the VAL function and it will be converted to UnicodeString before calling, transparent to you. If you insist on an AnsiString version, just make one that then calls the UnicodeString version. If you need an example, let me know, and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: @HeartWare it's will be inefficient, I don't want to convert my ansistring to unicode string :(

Comment: Do you need it for both integers and floating point? If only ints, I can make one for you. If floating point, it'll be too much of a hassle. But the implementation is located in System.pas

Comment: @loki Does it matter?  If this is in a bottleneck you probably wouldn't want an Ansi version of `.Val` either.

Comment: If this is a bottleneck then you won't want to pay for heap allocation either.

Comment: Can't you just call the function with Val( String( sYourAnsyString ), Result, Code) ?

Comment: @Stefaan The RTL does this already (see : `_ValExtL`).  No need to wrap it twice.

Comment: I found, it's _ValInt64 in system :) thanks for all ...

Comment: The code is located in _ValLong in System.Pas (for integer conversion). You can copy that out from there and modify it to accept an AnsiString, but I expect it will be less efficient than letting the Delphi compiler do it for you (unless you're really good at assembler and can use the assembler version).

Comment: @loki `_ValInt64` is not at all the same as `.Val`.  What is your real question?  How to efficiently convert a string to an integer?

Comment: If you take the PUREPASCAL version and modify it, I'll bet it'll be slower than just using the ASSEMBLER version and let the Delphi compiler convert the AnsiString to UnicodeString.

Comment: If performance when converting integer to string matters then the single biggest way to speed things up is to stop the darn heap allocation. Write a function that emits the decimal digits to a pre-allocated buffer. In my bespoke Delphi YAML emitter, that change alone (in my case in the context of emitting floating point values) improved performance by an order of magnitude.

Comment: My guess however is that the performance of your call to `Val` is not in fact a bottleneck.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's not integer->string, it's the other way around (but your point still stands).

Comment: OK, well in that case I can see why you might want to avoid a heap allocation in order to convert a string to an integer. But even so, don't do this until you are sure that performance really is a bottleneck.

Comment: The main issue is if the function needs to support hex and negative numbers. If it's only positive, decimal string numbers, it can be made quite easily. The more extra that the function needs to support, the more complex the implementation...

Comment: It is not rocket science. If you need an implementation for Integer only, simply do one for decimal and one for hex. The main loop multiplies the result by 10 (or shifts by 4 bits, in the case of hex) and adds the last digit found. HeartWare has that in 32 bit assembler. If you need it for other platforms, use PUREPASCAL.

Comment: FWIW, **next time you have a question like that**, simply **use** the function you are looking for, link with debug units and set a breakpoint. When the breakpoint is reached, single step into the code to find out its implementation. IMO, debugging is a skill that is not employed enough, these days.

Comment: Looks like `_ValLong` or `_ValExt` could do what you want, you can find their implementation in System. You can copy those functions and modify them, _but_ it must be said that there are Ansi versions of those functions that just cast their Ansi input to string before calling the unicode version, so the implementors of those functions didn't seem to worry about performance that much, maybe for a reason. ;)

Comment: @loki That's ridiculous.  `_ValLong` just does a direct cast to `string` and then calls `Val`, which is what you ostensibly want to avoid.  I think this question needs to be closed.

Comment: @j... but I updated (locally) the _ValLong to work with ansiString off course ;)

Comment: I'd be interested to know what your benchmarks say about performance in your app. You did do benchmarks?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did some a long time ago during my unicode transition... I had to rewrite half of the RTL and posted QC requests to implement all necessary low level functions for 8-bit strings too (never happened). I don't have exact numbers nor those benchmarks... but code with unnecessary conversion from ansi string to unicode took about 30 minutes... and without it about 3. Also at the time (2010) there were some discussions about similar issues going on on old NNTP forums.

Comment: @dalija the point is more about whether or not this call is a bottleneck

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you already have ansi string and you call that code often enough, then it certainly can be. And why start with ansi string (in my case UTF8) memory consumption and parsing speed - if parsing does not trigger any unnecessary unicode conversions. Yes, you can always optimize things another way and even get more speed, but this is the simplest way to get close to good performance.

Comment: @dalija Of course it can be. My question is whether or not it is. It's always a bad idea to optimise that which is not a bottleneck.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes i do some test, using modified vallong to work directly with ansiString make it from 30% to 100% faster than doing valong(string(xx)); tools to check is here; https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALStringBenchmark/win32/ALStringBenchmark.exe

Comment: Yes, but is this operation a bottleneck in your code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : yes it's was (mostly always moving from string to ansiString because tiny function like inttostr didn't exist for ansiString). Our app is server APP working on utf8 8 BIT string (in UTF8 and out UTF8), no way (it's will be stupid even) to migrate to 16 bit string ... so I was force to make a ansiString framework and this why I convert the ValLong function

Comment: If you really want to improve performance then try to avoid heap allocation completely.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree :) but my first target was to not decrease speed by migrating to delphi 2009+ but staying in ansiString  :) After it's always possible to do think better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *only* decimal digits, and *only* positive numbers, and *no* check for overflow (because you know it to never happen), then you can use the following function:

```
FUNCTION TryAnsiStrToInt(CONST S : AnsiString {EAX} ; OUT Value : Cardinal {EDX} ) : BOOLEAN; ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                PUSH    ESI
                MOV     ESI,EAX         // ESI = String
                XOR     ECX,ECX         // ECX = Value
                CLD
                XOR     EAX,EAX         // Clear upper 24 bits of EAX
        @LOOP:  LODSB                   // Load character
                OR      AL,AL           // End-of-String?
                JZ      @OK
                SUB     AL,'0'          // Convert ASCII to Binary
                JB      @ERR            // Out of range
                CMP     AL,9
                JA      @ERR            // Out of range
                IMUL    ECX,10          // ECX:=ECX*10
                ADD     ECX,EAX         // ECX:=ECX+EAX (ie. Value:=Value*10+Digit)
                JMP     @LOOP           // Next character
        @ERR:   XOR     AL,AL           // Error: Return FALSE
                XOR     ECX,ECX         // and Value:=0
                JMP     @OUT
        @OK:    MOV     AL,1            // Success return TRUE
        @OUT:   MOV     [EDX],ECX       // and Value
                POP     ESI
  END;
```

If you have additional requirements (negative numbers, hex numbers, overflow check etc.) you'll need to adapt the function to care for these...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  We also don't know if OP is targeting x64 or any other platforms where this won't work.

Comment: @heartWare thanks, it's a beginning but in fact i m targeting much more than just positive number :(

Comment: @loki If you specify your requirements (except floating points), I'll try to adapt the function to handle these. But the more options you want, the slower (by a miniscule amount) the function will be.